# Tool to identify all filepaths/filenames exceeding Windows' allowed length?

Tags: mac, windows, software-recommendation, file-sharing, microsoft-sharepoint

I have a folder containing several nested subfolders.

The parent folder is 1.2GB, and contains nearly **3,000 mainly screenshot image files**.

My Mac doesn't have a problem with the long filepaths/names obvs, but I now need to share these files with a very large **UK Authority running Windows** (not sure which version, as my Q has fallen on deaf ears so far...)

I think the only method I will be allowed to share the files by is OneDrive/Sharepoint - the Authority is restricted from using any other Cloud sharing method.

Due to the nesting (which has to stay) **many of the filenames/paths are too long, and One Drive is repeatedly rejecting over 1,200 of them without syncing.**

Pop-up error box only shows one offending filepath, helpfully doesn't offer a list of 'non-compliant' files.

**Is there a quick way of identifying and grouping the offending filenames/filepath names together so as I can rename them?**

I don't want to *batch* rename them in case that alters the meaning I've chosen for the individual file names, which are important.

Over 95% of the files are image-only files and evidence in an employee fraud investigation.  Each filename is important as it gives *context to the image*, hence me not wanting to use a batch tool to change the names to something shorter but unhelpful.

I don't mind going through them one by one, but need to know *which* are the 'offending' filenames/filepaths if I'm to do so.

It may be that I can also nest the folders slightly differently if I know which ones are causing the problems, as that may reduce the filepath length.

**Ideally I'm seeking a canny bit of software similar to MassReplaceIt** (which I've already used to find and replace 'illegal characters' in the filenames) but can use terminal command if no software exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, rename the folders & provide a key, that way you're not hoping that any name shortening needs to be entirely manual or intelligent.

Comment: Writing a key for nearly 3,000 files *and* renumbering them?    Gulp...  That's the rest of the month gone, then.

Comment: The folders, not the files. if you have file names approaching 260 chars, then you're going to struggle :P You could use `A:A1:AA1:Really really long file name` otherwise & just have to provide a key to the folder hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's probably partly due to the *degree* of nesting - none of the folder names are overly-long.  But some of the filenames probably are.  I just wish OneDrive would give you a *list* of the offending files instead of just refusing the jump and make you play detective.  I may well have to use your key idea (for which, thank you), but it is so much easier to see a name of a folder in a nest and think, "that needs investigating" and immediately click on it, rather than have to consult a separate key of folders.  The person looking at the evidence is neither young, nor a techie. 

Comment: I fully support your stance, but as you're stuck with Windows 'early 90s' file system, something's got to give ;))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming somewhat sane file/folder names

```
find TOPDIR | while read line; do [[ ${#line} -gt 1200 ]] && echo $line; done
```

will print all paths/files where the combined length exceeds 1200 characters. This should allow to spot troublesome folder names and rename them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  Is the limit really 1200?!

I thought I read somewhere it was much lower than that - 260 or something close to? 

So I'm entering this command in Terminal - what would I enter to get it to look *just* at the Parent file and nested contents, or will that command bring up every offending file in my Mac?  It’s just this particular project; I don't care about all my other files/folders.

Comment: Ah, I've just realised - or think I have – 'TOPDIR' in your advice above is the Parent folder name? Is that right?

Comment: @221b Yes, TOPDIR should be replaced by the parent folder name. Or you run `cd /to/parent/folder` and use `.` as TOPDIR. As for the 1200: I have no clue, I just picked the number you mentioned in the question.

Comment: 1200 is the *number* of files being rejected atm, not their filepath character count!

Comment: @221b Ah, reread the question :-)

Comment: Sorry, pressed return too soon!   1200 is the *number* of files being rejected atm, not their filepath character count!  And thank you, I tried by replacing TOPDIR with the Parent folder name and got this:                 ~ % find NHSFPTEST | while read line; do [[ ${#line} -gt 260 ]] && echo $line; done
find: NHSFPTEST: No such file or directory
myname@mynames-Air ~ %

Comment: Success!  Of sorts anyway.  I already guessed I had to move it out of OneDrive to run the terminal command.  I thought I'd pulled it locally, but it was still in iCloud.  Dragged it about again, through My Macbook Air > Macintosh HD > User > Me, ran the command again, and it spewed out a load of data... . About to paste it into a more readable format and see if I can edit the filenames/paths manually - or what will be the best move, but now I can at least see *which filenames/filepath names are causing the problems* - thanks very much!